# Tuning Arabic (Syrian Oud)

Tags: tuning, oud

I bought a new Oud **(11 strings)**. It has been a week and still I can't get it tuned. Does anyone know how to tune it? I was told it should be tuned this way: **(C F A d g c)**, but I don't know what big letters and small letters mean in this case.

I also want to know, what does the number means, where it says **(Mhz)** on the tuner.

Comment: I hope it doesn't say MHz on the tuner. You'd need heavy industrial equipment to achieve high enough tension to get the pitch up to that range... (Apart from the fact that the strings would tear long before you get there.)

Comment: It says Mhz and a number under it, i think 540 or 440 im not sure, im using a guitar clip on tuner. what should i do?

Comment: That'll be [440 Hz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A440_(pitch_standard)).

Comment: should i keep it at 440 HZ?

Comment: I don't know what's typically used for Oud, but in doubt yes, 440 Hz is a pretty widely used standard across the world.

Comment: lots of good info here: http://www.oudcafe.com/stringing_and_tuning.htm

Comment: also found this "then it really doesn't matter whether you choose one of the Turkish or one of the Arabic tunings, as long as you get appropriate strings for that tuning and tension based on your oud. Using improper strings at too high tension can destroy your oud, so check with your oud maker if you're unsure which strings and tuning is right for your instrument." here: http://www.daviderath.com/oud/tuning-notation

Comment: I recommend you get a better tuner -- Korg makes excellent, inexpensive ones

Comment: I think Doktor Mayhem covered it with his answer. One thing about the letter casing: they denote different octaves. So (omitting the pairs): `C F A` would be the lower octave, `d g` would be middle octave, and the highest string would actually be `c'`, which is an octave higher than `c` (this `c` is the note `rast` and is not found in an open string) and two octaves higher than `C`. So the tuning would be `C F A d g c'`. I hope this helps in understanding the letter casing. Some ouds are also specially built in a way that you can tune them to `F A d g c' f'`.

Comment: Also regarding tuning, CFAdgc' is a widely used tuning in the Arabic oud, but not the only one. There are other tunings musicians use because of different traditions they come from, preference, etc. Some other examples are given in the Oudcafe page that Doktor Mayhem shared in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Capital letters are the lower pitched, bass strings and the Lower-Case letters are the higher strings.

So your bottom C is a single string, and the others are tuned as matched pairs, with your top four strings (A d g c) as fourths. I would start with your A, then tune your F and C downwards from there, and then work upwards tuning your higher strings. It doesn't really matter, but if you are having trouble this should make it easier as you should be able to tune fourths without the tuner.

Regarding the 440 - that is the most common standard for A to be tuned to. So if your tuner is set to 440Hz I'd recommend leaving it there.

Just to consolidate a couple of the comments:

[Daviderath.com](http://www.daviderath.com/oud/tuning-notation) has somestraightforward guidance on tuning notation, and [Oudcafe](http://www.oudcafe.com/stringing_and_tuning.htm) has guidance on tuning and on stringing your Oud, including this handy picture:

[image]

Comment: But in the Tuner there is no lower and upper case letters, there is a letter with a pound(#) on top of it. is that for higher strings. by the way thank you for replying !!!

Comment: The tuner will tell you the name of the note, and different tuners have different indicators for each octave. Your instructions should say, or you can just experiment - move up one string playing the notes and see what the tuner indicates as you go up or down by an octave.

Comment: You might want to add sentence explaining the meaning of the "2" and "1" there -- identifying the octave re middle C

Comment: Normally I would Carl, however here the c1 and c2 are unison, not an octave apart. Ouds tend to be that way.